# Dynamically populate a filed in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet called "Base Sheet" in following format

```
 Order#    Weight
 1213      345
 1213      567
 3450      111
 3450      222
 3451      444
```

I group by based on "Order #" and sum "Weight" and populate in a sheet called "Weight"

```
Order#    Total_Weight    Deleted_Status
1213       912
3450       333
3451       444
```

I do the grouping and summing using "ALASQL" library.

```
var res_1 = alasql('SELECT [0] as Order#, sum([1]) as Total_Weight FROM ? GROUP BY [0]',[row]);
```

My challenge is if an "Order#" is completely deleted from "Base Sheet" then the corresponding "Order#" in the "Weight" sheet should have the "Deleted_Status" as "Yes".

Let's say we delete Order# "3451" from Base sheet, then in "Weight" sheet it has to be

```
Order#    Total_Weight    Deleted_Status
1213       912
3450       333
3451       444            Yes
```

Not sure how to implement this logic in Google Apps Script dynamically. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your current situation and your goal as follows.

- You have 2 sheets in a Google Spreadsheet.

  - One is a sheet which has the sheet name of `Base Sheet`.
  - Another is a sheet which has the sheet name of `Weight`.
- When the value of "Order#" is removed from `Base Sheet`, you want to put a value of `Yes` to the column "C" of the same "Order#" in the sheet `Weight`.
- You want to run the script when the cell value is removed and the row is deleted.
- You want to achieve your goal using Google Apps Script.

In this case, I would like to propose to use the trigger as follows.

- For detecting the manually deleted cell value, the simple trigger of OnEdit is used.
- For detecting the manually deleted rows, the installable trigger of OnChange is used.

The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And, if you want to detect not only the manually deleted cell value, but also the manually deleted rows, [please install the OnChange trigger to the function `onEdit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually).

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Base Sheet") return;
  const obj = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().reduce((o, [a]) => Object.assign(o, {[a]: true}), {});
  const sheetWheight = e.source.getSheetByName("Weight");
  const values = sheetWheight.getRange(2, 1, sheetWheight.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().map(([a]) => [obj[a] ? "" : "Yes"]);
  sheetWheight.getRange(2, 3, values.length, 1).setValues(values);
}
```

- In this script, the sheet names of `Base Sheet` and `Weight` are used. These are from your question. If those sheet names are different from your actual situation, please modify above script.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, I prepared in order to detect both the manually deleted cell value and the manually deleted rows. So for example, when `3451` in "Base Sheet" is removed, `Yes` is put to the column "C" of "3451" in "Weight". And also, when `3451` in "Base Sheet" is added, `Yes` is removed from the column "C" of "3451" in "Weight".

  - If you don't want to remove `Yes` even when the same "Order#" is added, please tell me.
- **This sample script is run by the trigger. So when you directly run the function `onEdit`, an error occurs. Please be careful this. When you want to run the script, please manually remove "Order#" in the sheet "Base Sheet".**

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Answer (score 0):

Since an existing script is copying the orders and combined weights to the "Weight" sheet, could you not just use an in-sheet formula to produce the results of the "Deleted_Status" column?

For instance, suppose your "Order#" and "Weight" columns in 'Base Sheet' are in A:B, that your "Order#" and "Total_Weight" columns in the 'Weight' sheet are also in A:B, and that the "Deleted_Status" column is Weight!C:C. You could place the following formula in C1 of an otherwise empty Column C:

`=ArrayFormula({"Deleted_Status"; IF(A2:A="",,IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A,'Base Sheet'!A:A,1,FALSE))),,"Yes"))})`

This formula creates the header in the first cell. If cell A2:A (in the current 'Weight' sheet) is blank, the corresponding cell in C2:C remains null. Otherwise, if the value of that cell is found in Column A of 'Base Sheet' (i.e., `IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP`), the cell remains null. If it *is* an error (i.e., if the A2:A value is not found there), the result is `Yes`.